# sample size of identically distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $Y_1$,...,$Y_n$ are independent and identically distributed random variables how big does the sample size n need to be such that the probability of $(Y_1+...+Y_n)/n$ being inside two standard deviation of $\mu$,is at leas 98%

I tried to use the tschebyscheff inequality ($P(|Y-\mu|>n*\sigma)\leq1/n^2$), but i it didn't work.
thanks in advance

Comment: I think I'm not understanding the question.  Isn't the probability already $96$% for a single datum?  And the sample mean should get even closer as $n$ increases.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor you are right, when should it at least be 98%. I'll edit it

Comment: @RobertTheTutor You're assuming that $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ are normal and they might not be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming that your $\ Y\ $ is $\ \frac{\sum_\limits{i=1}^nY_i}{n}\ $—which is what you need to be putting in the Chebyshev inequality—then the variance of $\ Y\ $ is $\ \frac{\sigma^2}{n}\ $, where $\ \sigma^2\ $ is the common variance of the $\ Y_i\ $.
[Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Probabilistic_statement) therefore gives you
\begin{align}
P\Bigg(\Big|Y-\mu\Big|\le\frac{k\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\Bigg)&=1-P\Bigg(\Big|Y-\mu\Big|>\frac{k\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\Bigg)\\
&\ge1-\frac{1}{k^2}
\end{align}
for any positive $\ \epsilon\ $. Can you see how to choose $\ k $ and $\ n\ $ to give you the inequality you're looking for?

Comment: I think so, i need to set $ \frac{ k  }{\sqrt{n}}$= 2 and i need $1-\frac{ 1}{k^2}=0,98$

Comment: Yes, you've got the right idea, but $\ n\ $ must be a positive integer, and $\ 1-\frac{1}{k^2}=0,98\ $ and $\ \frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}=2\ $ gives you $\ n=25,5\ $ which isn't an integer. However, since you only really need  $\ 1-\frac{1}{k^2}\ge0,98\ $, you don't need to make $\ n\ $ *equal* to $\ 25,5\ $.

Comment: yeah i got the same for n, thank you for the help